# Как лучше наследовать обычный класс от дженерика в С#

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование, generics

Как написать наследование обычного класса от дженерика или это не совсем правильная практика?

```
using System;

public class Program{
    public static void Main(){

        var obj1 = new Child<int>(25);
        obj1.objectType();      
    }
}

class Child : Parent<T> {

    public Child(int num){
        this.obj = num;
    }
}

class Parent<T>{
    T obj;

    public Parent(T obj)    { this.obj = obj; }

    public void objectType(){
        Console.WriteLine("Тип : " + typeof(T));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наследовать от обобщенного класса можно и такое решение оправдано. Но при этом нужно либо чтобы новый класс тоже был обобщенным, либо указывал конкретный тип параметра.

Т.е. либо:

```
class Child<T> : Parent<T>
{
    public Child(T num) : base(num)
    {
    }
}
```

Либо:

```
class Child : Parent<int>
{
    public Child(int num) : base(num)
    {
    }
}
```

P.S. Как верно заметил @Grundy, нужно вызывать базовый конструктор.

Comment: по идее в дочернем классе конструктор не нужен, в конкретно данном случае, потому что он то же поле `obj` устанавливает. Даже еще интереснее, нет вызова базового конструктора и это вообще все должно упасть :-)

Comment: @Grundy да, точно. Скопировал код автора и не обратил на это внимания.